# Chaining PHP PDO query

Tags: php, pdo, chaining

I'm not sure if "chaining" is the correct term for this but what I'm asking is if its possible to make a PDO query similar to this MySQLi query...

```
$sql = mysqli_fetch_object($db->query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE userID = 1");
```

with PDO I have only been able to do it this way

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE userID = 1");
$query = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

is it possible to "chain" (please correct me if there is a better term for that) the query with PDO or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT username FROM member WHERE userID = 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the method chaining is good only for `query()` method but doesn't work for the prepare/execute.

So, for this purpose I'd suggest to extend PDO with one little helper function like this

```
public function run($sql, $bind = array())
{
    $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($bind);
    return $stmt;
}
```

so you can use it like

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM member WHERE userID = ?";
$name = $db->run($sql, [1])->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually chain prepared inserts and updates:

```
$data = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `data` (data_key, data_value) VALUES (:data_key, :data_value)')->execute($args);
$data = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `data` SET data_value = :data_value WHERE data_key = :data_key')->execute($args);
```

You cannot chain execution in prepared select.